# how can I put a string into php in jquery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to output a value in PHP, something like the example below. How can I achieve this?

```
var number='1';
var $user_link = "<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain('" + number + "') ?>";
```

Comment: It is not possible in way you are trying to do, because the back-end part (php) renders before client side (javascript)

Comment: Also doesn't make sense that you can hard code a value for `number` but need to use it as a variable on next line. Maybe you need to use a php variable instead? If you already have it as php variable, use it within php function

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple-three ways of going about this:

(1) Use an event driven Ajax call that passes the value of the variable *number* to a PHP script, returning JSON, which is then embedded into the page using JavaScript and the DOM.

(2)Submit the page to the server, passing the value of the variable *number* as a parameter in a GET query string or a hidden input in a POST.

(3)Take the functionality of bp_core_get_user_domain and put it into a JS function, and forget PHP altogether, unless you're using a PHP global variable to do something.  In which case you can just put that data into a cookie on the original page request and let JavaScript read it without having to resubmit the  page.

Comment: and #4, if value is already known at server can run function by using it as php variable

Comment: lol..not always, look how the 2 language are getting mangled here

Comment: Yeah well, every rocket scientist had to learn simple addition at some point.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be condescending, the reality however is sometimes the obvious needs to be pointed out when people run into these sorts of issues

Comment: If you need PHP data, I generally go with option 1. It's the cleanest solution and keeps things nicely separated, so you're not blurring the lines between PHP and JS. Or do option 3, if you don't need PHP.

Comment: Also with option 1, you get the ability to retrieve that PHP data anywhere in your application, so it's data that you need all over the place, that's a good option. There is a performance hit in making the Ajax call.